# Disable refresh of target on build

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm using tycho to build my rcp application. Sadly, today I have to release the first internal milestone, but one of the projects I'm using is down (The great LWJGL -  http://www.lwjgl.org/) and consequently my build fails because I cannot resolve an entry of my target platform.

Does there is a way to disable such update?

Note that I already have build my app, hence I already have downloaded all the LWJGL's jars and p2 stuff. Now I simply want to use the version of LWJGL I already have to build my RCP application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a corresponding Eclipse p2 bug that needs update site checking for the target platform - that's why maven offline mode does not work as expected. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337022

For later, I suggest building a mirror of critical outside sites. In that case you could at least redirect the build to that. E.g. b3 aggregator can be used for this: http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/b3/

Answer (score 1):

try maven offline mode (mvn -o)

Comment: not working... it still tries to update the target platform :-(